# Cannot import psq in application (multiprocessing import error)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm working on switching my app over to GAE, but am running into an issue getting pub/sub working. I'm really not sure why this is happening... the *only* thing I can think is I have a conflicting package, but I'm honestly not sure.

The traceback looks like this:

```
File "/home/nhanlon/dev/.../backend/api/restapi/Resources/Matches.py", line 8, in <module>
    import psq
  File "/home/nhanlon/dev/.../backend/api/lib/psq/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .worker import MultiprocessWorker, Worker
  File "/home/nhanlon/dev/.../backend/api/lib/psq/worker.py", line 18, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 41, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags
```

Here's my requirements.txt (installed to $PROJECT_ROOT/lib and setup in appengine_config.py)

```
amqp==1.4.9
aniso8601==1.1.0
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.22
celery==3.1.20
click==4.1
colorlog==2.7.0
enum34==1.0.4
eventlet==0.17.4
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Cors==2.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.4
flask-restplus==0.8.0
Flask-SocketIO==1.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
gcloud==0.15.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.1.0
greenlet==0.4.9
httplib2==0.9.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
kombu==3.0.33
MarkupSafe==0.23
newrelic==2.60.0.46
oauth2client==2.1.0
opentok==2.3.0
protobuf==3.0.0b3
psq==0.3.0
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-engineio==0.8.1
python-socketio==0.7.0
pytz==2015.7
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.8.1
rethinkdb==2.1.0.post2
retrying==1.3.3
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.10.4
```

Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: You should probably advise if this is meant to be running under appengine (traditional deployment) or using flexible runtime. If the former then a number of these libraries don't seem appropriate.

Comment: @TimHoffman why can't they run under appengine? Which libraries exactly don't seem appropriate?

Comment: To be honest I am not going to go through them all, but the first I checked has this in it's description - `Greenlets are provided as a C extension module for the regular unmodified interpreter.`  now if your running the traditional appengine that is clearly not supported, hence my question.  Also I can't see how greenlets would be useful in a front facing appengine instance.